# Base64 Linux and Windows

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, base64

Given this string: `ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆa,` generated with SecureRandom with the next method:

```
public String getSalt() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String salt = null;

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] saltArr = new byte[64];
    random.nextBytes(saltArr);

    salt = new String(saltArr).trim();

    return salt;
}
```

**TLDR: scroll to bottom**

Then the returned string is "formated" to avoid special characters:

```
String salt = getSalt();
salt = salt.replace("<", "!");
salt = salt.replace(">", "!");
salt = salt.replace("\"", "!");
salt = salt.replace("'", "!");
salt = salt.replace("\\", "!");
salt = salt.replace("&", "!");
```

Encoding the salt:

```
public String getEncryptedSalt(String chain) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = chain.getBytes();
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
    String salt = new String(encodedBytes);

    return salt;
}
```

Decoding the salt:

```
public String getDecryptedSalt(String chain) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = chain.getBytes();
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(bytes);
    String decrypted = new String(decodedBytes);

    return decrypted;
}
```

Hashing the password (decoded salt+pwd):

```
public String getHash(String target) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    sh.update(target.getBytes());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : sh.digest()) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & b));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Why am I getting different results on the same string (above) on different OS?**

Code sample:

```
 String salt = "ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆ`a,";
 String encodedSalt = getEncryptedSalt(salt);
 String decodedSalt = getDecryptedSalt(encodedSalt);
 String pwd = "AbcD12345";
 String hashed = getHash(salt+pwd);
```

Windows sample:

```
 SALT: ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆ`a, 
 SALT ENCODED: 0Unz3TfhAx3UdFaGsGR21OaKhCHPrT004Cm1IBnFIdrjzYO4p2Puo9ZvmmFV1RndgPcb93CzAgg28qWIYGEDLA== 
 SALT DECODED: ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆ`a, 

 PWD: AbcD12345 
 SALT+PWD: b0d87c79895a59bb52227eaf4aac01437676c3494a5493690c87b76efbe260e41082b6c53d811e8de4c612142eca82b970d6bba42e71cc90efa26c74e08155
```

Linux - Debian7 sample:

```
 SALT: ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆ`a, 
 SALT ENCODED: w5FJw7PDnTfDoQMdw5R0VuKAoMKwZHbDlMOmxaDigJ4hw4/CrT00w6ApwrUgGcOFIcOaw6PDjcaSwrjCp2PDrsKjw5ZvxaFhVcOVGcOd4oKsw7cbw7dwwrMCCDbDssKly4ZgYQMs 
 SALT DECODED: ÑIóÝ7áÔtV†°dvÔæŠ„!Ï­=4à)µ Å!ÚãÍƒ¸§cî£ÖošaUÕÝ€÷÷p³6ò¥ˆ`a, 

 PWD: AbcD12345 
 SALT+PWD: e0c31f603f36a6d1c5db1a64ebe01bbc3d51f0544d319535bbf8c345a1b7fe2fb68a98d1175a98eedf26e1a441528583a4cc285954e26a56f9d23d7174ea2
```

Even tough the salt is the same on both systems, the encoded salts are different but the decoded salts are the same, why? Why does this affect the password if its only a string sum of salt+password?

**PD:** the least I dont understand is that: the salt and pwd are saved in a MySQL database. If I create a user in Windows then export the database to Linux he wont be able to authenticate due to incorrect password. But if then I create a user in Linux and export the database to Windows he **will** be able to authenticate...

Comment: `Base64` has nothing to do with encryption nor decryption

Comment: @specializt ok then why the hashes are different ? btw thats how i called the methods

Answer (score 1):

You are using `new String(bytes)` in a number of places. This will interpret the bytes and convert them to characters using the default [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of your system.

The default character encoding on Windows is different from the default character encoding on Linux, therefore the results will be different.

Avoid using the default character encoding; specify the character encoding explicitly. For example:

```
salt = new String(saltArr, "UTF-8").trim();

String salt = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");

String decrypted = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
```

**edit** Even if you do this, this is probably not going to work:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] saltArr = new byte[64];
random.nextBytes(saltArr, "UTF-8");
```

You are generating random bytes and then you are interpreting those bytes as if they are encoded characters (using some character encoding). This might throw an exception if the random bytes are for example not valid UTF-8 sequences.

Strings are not suitable as containers for random bytes. Don't try to create strings out of random bytes this way. Instead of this, do Base 64 encoding *before* you put the bytes in a `String`. Or generate random *characters* instead of random *bytes* for the salt.

Comment: if i use UTF-8 for the salt I get even a more strange result, tried it and doesnt work either, Salt as UTF8 c o����gl�|^�!.d�|���ͬ�zE�Y���h鮰�A,�!�5~��$��k�M�

Comment: I will end up as i first tought, generate something that should not dpeend on system variables. Probably in stead of base64 it would be easier to use something like AES and create the random salt as simple numbers and letters

Comment: Also, `string.getBytes()` has the same problem in the other direction.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström can you post a code example please?

Comment: � is what you get when you generate an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: @Alpha2k: Solution is simple, don't store your random bytes in a string. Only at the end, encode a byte array to a Base64 string.

Comment: @Alpha2k: I don't know what you're talking about. Just write your random bytes to a `ByteArrayOutputStream baos`, and at the end `Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray())`.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the salt from:

```
public String getSalt() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
String salt = null;

SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] saltArr = new byte[64];
random.nextBytes(saltArr);

salt = new String(saltArr).trim();

return salt;
}
```

To

```
public String getSalt() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
}
```

Less complex but less errors.